# Is NP countable?

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity

Is NP countable?

I am confused with this problem. I think it is not countable but I am not sure.
Can someone prove whether it is countable?

Please show your proof. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

A problem is NP if there is a non-deterministic Turing machine which computes the answer in polynomial time.

Are there uncountably many non-deterministic Turing machines are there?

Comment: Yeah I think that are uncountably many non-deterministic Turing machine

Comment: @Help321: How can you write down a Turing machine?

Comment: My bad there are countably many non-deterministic Turing machine so NP must be countable